# twitter unity webapp has mobile view

Tags: unity, webapps, twitter

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and installed the unity webapp for twitter. But I only get mobile view of the twitter client

[image]

How can I change this back to the desktop view as it was before on ubuntu 15.10 and earlier ?